# Automatically assign a number of tasks to a specific/user/group

Tags: 2010, workflow

How do you make a workflow, where in if the user belong to a specific group, a number of tasks will be assigned automatically to the user. 
Thanks!

Comment: your question is not too much clear. When do the workflow have to start?